With Compose, how can I show a navigation bar only on a sub navigation graph
I'm making a Kotlin Multiplatform / Compose Multiplatform app. I want this sort of graph :

SplashScreen
AuthScreen
MainGraph

HomeScreen
...
SettingsScreen



I want a navigation bar to navigate through my main graph, but obviously, I don't want to have this navigation bar when I'm on my SplashScreen or AuthScreen. I thought it would be easy but strangely I can't find any post asking this or anything in the documentation about that. And ChatGPT keeps giving me code that doesn't even work.
I've tried using another NavHost in a composable block but it won't work. Like that :
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Destination.Splash
) {
    composable<Destination.Splash> {
        SplashScreenRoot()
    }
    composable<Destination.Auth> {
        AuthScreenRoot()
    }
    composable<Destination.Main> {
        // Add navigation here
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Destination.Main.Home
        ) {
            composable<Destination.Main.Home> {
                HomeScreenRoot()
            }
            composable<Destination.Main.Settings> {
                SettingsScreenRoot()
            }
        }
    }
}

I've seen a way to do this by having a nav bar and showing it depending on the current route but it seems weird that there wouldn't be a cleaner way to do this seeing as it is a pretty basic situation.

You can do it by setting a nested NavHost that contains navigation bar with a Scaffold.
val navController = rememberNavController()
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Destination.Splash
) {
    composable<Destination.Splash> {
        SplashScreenRoot()
    }
    composable<Destination.Auth> {
        AuthScreenRoot()
    }
    composable<Destination.Main> {
        MainContainer()
       
    }
}

And MainContainer that contains nested NavHost with bottom navigation
@Composable
private fun MainContainer() {

    val nestedNavController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        bottomBar = {
            NavigationBar {

            }
        }
    ) { paddingValues: PaddingValues ->
        NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
            navController = nestedNavController,
            startDestination = Destination.Main.Home
        ) {
            addBottomNavigationGraph()
        }
    }
}

You can check full sample in github repo.

Oh, I was using the same navController for both NavHosts, that's why it kept crashing. Thanks a lot !
